# Combining parameter and value while reading in csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

If I have a document like this, with the column names repeated in row 1 and row 2 and the unit of the parameter in row 3, how do I call pd.read_csv such that it creates a data frame with the headers having the column name and unit and the values?

```
Time    Speed   Torque
time    speed   torque 
seconds m/s Nm 
1   4000    229,5
2   4000    228,7
3   4000    230,1
```

Answer (score 1):

If want `MultiIndex` in columns use parameters `header=[0,1]` for convert first and second row without skipped row(s):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Time    Speed   Torque
time    speed   torque 
seconds m/s Nm 
1   4000    229,5
2   4000    228,7
3   4000    230,1"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=[0,1], skiprows=[0])
print (df)
     time speed torque
  seconds   m/s     Nm
0       1  4000  229,5
1       2  4000  228,7
2       3  4000  230,1

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['speed', 'time', 'torque'], ['Nm', 'm/s', 'seconds']],
           labels=[[1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 0]])
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Time    Speed   Torque
time    speed   torque 
seconds m/s Nm 
1   4000    229,5
2   4000    228,7
3   4000    230,1"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", header=[0,1], skiprows=[1])
print (df)
     Time Speed Torque
  seconds   m/s     Nm
0       1  4000  229,5
1       2  4000  228,7
2       3  4000  230,1
```

If want omit second and third rows use only `skiprows` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Time    Speed   Torque
time    speed   torque 
seconds m/s Nm 
1   4000    229,5
2   4000    228,7
3   4000    230,1"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", skiprows=[1, 2])
print (df)
   Time  Speed Torque
0     1   4000  229,5
1     2   4000  228,7
2     3   4000  230,1
```